attempt to concatenate string with nil | Roblox Code, How to fix?
I've been working on a GUI system where I have a health, stamina and EXP bar.
Once I finally got towards the end, I was given an error message on this part of code, saying:
attempt to concatenate string with nil
HealthDisplay.Text = "HP:  " .. Humanoid.Health .. "/" .. Humanoid.MaxHealth
StaminaDisplay.Text = "Stamina:  " .. Stamina.Value .. "/" .. MaxStamina.Value
LvlDisplay.Text = "Lvl:  " .. Level.Value

Im not sure how to fix this.
I tried using the "tostring()" function but it would only say "nil" on the bars rather than the number.

Where are you getting your variables from? It's unclear what your variables are and their types. Please edit your question to show what each variable is.

The issue is that one or multiple the Humanoid.Health, Humanoid.MaxHealth, Stamina.Value, MaxStamina.value, Level.Value variables are empty(nil).
Try printing them out one by one untill you find every single empty variable there is. After that, try finding out why they are empty - try looking for them in your files (or the documentation if it's a constant).
